# GDI+ DrawString() on Windows 8 truncating string

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-8, gdi+, gdi

The following code displays the same string differently between Windows 7 (and previous versions of Windows) and Windows 8:

```
Graphics graphics(ps.hdc);

std::unique_ptr<StringFormat> format(StringFormat::GenericDefault()->Clone());
Font font(L"Segoe UI", static_cast<Gdiplus::REAL>(17.5), FontStyleBold, UnitPixel);     
format->SetTrimming(StringTrimmingNone);
std::wstring name("rt");
RectF rectName;
graphics.MeasureString(name.c_str(), -1, &font, PointF(20, 20), format.get(), &rectName);           

graphics.DrawString(name.c_str(), -1, &font, rectName, format.get(), &SolidBrush(Color()));

graphics.DrawRectangle(&Pen(Color(255, 0, 0)), rectName);
```

In Windows 7, I get the string 'rt' inside the rectangle as it should appear. In Windows 8, the only the first letter 'r' appears. This only seems to happen with certain character pairs. For example, the string 're' displays correctly in both operating systems.  The rectangle returned from MeasureString() appears to be the same in both Windows 7 and Windows 8. Is there any explanation for this difference?

Comment: GDI+ is pretty infamous for inconsistent text rendering.  The Windows 8 angle could be a different video adapter DPI setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MeasureString` is known to fudge the numbers at times in the name of efficiency. It will do some guess-work and then pad the RectF it populates so that to [hopefully] make it big enough for DrawString to work. I suspect that something has either changed with respect to font rendering, or maybe the system's hinting settings are different and that is causing trouble when it comes time for DrawString to actually fit the text in the RectF.

.NET's Measure string method actually documents this as such in [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> The MeasureString method is designed for use with individual strings
>   and includes a small amount of extra space before and after the string
>   to allow for overhanging glyphs. Also, the DrawString method adjusts
>   glyph points to optimize display quality and might display a string
>   narrower than reported by MeasureString.

As a workaround, you can ask MeasureString to do some more precise glyph measurements by using

```
std::unique_ptr<StringFormat> format(StringFormat::GenericTypographic()->Clone());
```

instead of

```
std::unique_ptr<StringFormat> format(StringFormat::GenericDefault()->Clone());
```

Comment: Using GenericTypographic() seemed to fix my problem! I determined it was specifically the flag StringFormatFlagsNoWrap that fixes it. It seems the second character was actually getting wrapped to the next line, but since the height of the bounding rectangle wasn't great enough, I couldn't see it. It still doesn't make sense why Windows 8's DrawString() wraps to the next line even though MeasureString() returns a rectangle wide enough to display the string on one line, but this seems like a good workaround. Thanks!